probability that the failure is on the individual as observed
In his paper Regression Models and Life Tables, where he introduced the proportional hazard model, David Cox states that:

For the particular failure at time $t_{(i)}$, conditionally on the risk set $\mathscr{R}(t_{(i)})$, the probability that the failure is on the individual as observed is

$$
\frac{e^{\vec\beta\cdot\vec{z}_{(i)}}}{\sum_{l\in \mathscr{R}(t_{(i)})} e^{\vec{\beta}\cdot\vec{z}_{(l)}}} .
\tag{$\ast$}
$$
Here $\mathscr R(t_{(i)})$ denotes the set risk set, defined as The set of individuals at risk at time $t -0$.
The expotential functions are part of the hazard functions. In Cox's model, one assumes that
$$
\lambda(t) = \lambda_0(t) e^{\vec\beta\cdot\vec z},
$$
where $\lambda_0(t)$ is a “universal” unknown function that takes care of the time dependence of the hazard function, and $\vec z$ are the measurements available for each individual.
AS Cox himself mentions,

The main problem considered in this paper is that of assessing the relation between the distribution of failure time and $\vec z$.
This will be done in terms of a model in which the hazard is
$$
\lambda(t) = \lambda_0(t) e^{\vec\beta\cdot\vec z},
$$
where $\vec\beta$ is a vector of unknown parameters and $\lambda_0(t)$ is an unknown function
giving the hazard function for the standard set of conditions $\vec z = \vec 0$.

For each individual $\vec{z}$, a hazard function $\lambda(t,\vec z)$ is obtained, and $(\ast)$ can be seen as
$$
\frac{\lambda(t,\vec{z}_{(i)})}{\sum_{l\in \mathscr{R}(t_{(i)})}\lambda(t,\vec{z}_{(l)})}.
\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Question.  What probability (in symbols) are we computing in $(\ast)$ and why can it be expressed using the hazard function, as $(\dagger)$ shows?.
As Cox defines,
$$
\lambda(t) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\mathbf{P}(t\leq T< t+h \mid T\geq t)}{h} = - \frac{S'(t)}{S(t)},
$$
where $S(t)$ denotes the survival function.
From this definition, I understand that no probability should be described by $\lambda$.

Could you elaborate on your final statement?  After all, $\lambda$ isn't even a probability; and the logic of your assertion is obscure.

Hi @whuber, thanks for your comment. The way I see $\lambda$, it is not a probability but a change in the probability (at least in the continuous case, which what I'm concerned about now). That is why it seems odd to me that the probability of $(\dagger)$, whatever it is, may be expressed in terms of $\lambda$, since it's a rate and not an actual probability. I hope that helps clarify my last sentence

First, the definition of $\lambda(t)$ at the end of the question holds for continuous-time models. That's a general definition of the hazard function for any continuous probability distribution; it's not restricted to survival analysis although that's where it most typically is used. In the survival context, it's the instantaneous probability of an event given that the individual hasn't yet had the event.
With a Cox model, you use the instantaneous probability of an event at an observed discrete event time.
Second, I think that this is easiest to understand if you start from the bottom (your $\dagger$) and work back to the top (your *).
Consider
$$
\frac{\lambda(t,\vec{z}_{(i)})}{\sum_{l\in \mathscr{R}(t_{(i)})}\lambda(t,\vec{z}_{(l)})}.\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
The hazard for each individual is the instantaneous probability of an event at that event time. The denominator is the sum of those probabilities over all individuals in the risk set at that time. The numerator is the probability for the individual experiencing the event at that time. So that ratio is the probability that that particular individual had the event, among all of those who might have had it. That's straightforward if there are no tied event times; there are nevertheless ways to handle tied event times if they occur.
Then you can simplify using $\lambda(t,\vec{z}_{(l)})= \lambda_0(t) e^{\vec\beta\cdot\vec z_{(l)}}$. The $\lambda_0(t)$ factor is present in both the numerator and denominator, so it cancels. That gives:
$$
\frac{e^{\vec\beta\cdot\vec{z}_{(i)}}}{\sum_{l\in \mathscr{R}(t_{(i)})} e^{\vec{\beta}\cdot\vec{z}_{(l)}}} .
\tag{$\ast$}
$$

Thanks for your answer. Sadly, I think there's been some misunderstanding. I know how to get from $(\ast)$ to $(\dagger)$ and vice versa. My trouble is trying to understand what either of those expressions is actually computing. And I don't agree with you on one thing, which could be a source of conflict. Related to the answer to whuber, I don't think $\lambda$ is an instantaneous probability, but rather the instantaneous change in probability.

Finally, in this fragment of the paper, Cox still considers the continuous setting (I also have troubles understanding the discrete case, but let's do one at a time). My goal is to understand what $(\ast)$ is computing, in symbols, hoping that maybe that what I understand the corresponding display.
